# How to change Django Builtin dev Server inside a Docker container?

Tags: django, docker

The Django builtin Development Server has the "feature" of filtering out HTTP Headers containing underscores:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/7785e03ba89aafbd949191f126361fb9103cb980/django/core/servers/basehttp.py

```
def get_environ(self):
    # Strip all headers with underscores in the name before constructing
    # the WSGI environ. This prevents header-spoofing based on ambiguity
    # between underscores and dashes both normalized to underscores in WSGI
    # env vars. Nginx and Apache 2.4+ both do this as well.
    for k in self.headers:
        if '_' in k:
            del self.headers[k]

    return super().get_environ()
```

For development purposes, i'd like to comment out this for loop. I run Django inside a Docker container. How can I comment out these lines when building the image?

Comment: you probably shouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

HTTP servers forbid underscores in HTTP header names. So you should not comment out that for loop or do anything like that. Rather you can -

Set the header as YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADER

> use a hyphen, not underscore

Get the header as request.headers.get('YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER')